# SQL Server-> PHP connection with odbc and special characters

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I've a problem with getting accented characters from SQL Server using odbc with this string -> "$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database;"

[image: bad encoding]

Answer (score 0):

Done! iconv("CP1252", "UTF-8", $text);